# How to add/create categories in a SharePoint wiki?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-wiki, categories

When editing a page, I see the place where I think I should be able to add categories, but I can't select or type anything (either in the box or the symbol to the right). Do I need to enable categories somehow?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Man, this took me an embarrassingly long amount of time to figure out, so don't feel bad.

But if you go to the library settings for your enterprise wiki, and open up the settings for the categories field, you'll notice that you need to actually assign it a managed metadata termset before you can have users enter items into it.

**Some instructions:**
My environment is currently transitioning to 2013, so the screenshots are in 2010-mode.  Shouldn't be a problem, most things are more or less in the same place.

1. Go to the library settings on your enterprise wiki library:
   [image: Edit those sweet, sweet library settings]
2. We need to edit the column.  You can do this on the library directly (look under Columns) or you can do this on the content type.  I prefer to work out of the content type.  So, under Content Types, select Enterprise Wiki Page:
   [image: List columns are for chumps; content types 4 lyfe]
3. Next, click Wiki Categories:
   [image: We're almost there...]
4. Then, click the "Edit column" link next to the column name:
   [image: I have 0 funny things left to say.]
5. On the Column Settings page, about half way down, you'll find Term Set Settings (no screenshot, sorry, too much identifying information here).  This is where you assign a term set.  You should see a metadata service that you can drill into.

Of course, this is all assuming your enterprise has set up a managed metadata service.  If you haven't, and you're not the farm admin, you'll need to contact someone in charge to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am still kind of struggling. First of all I'm getting hung up on the terminology - I want to use the Categories feature that shows up by default on every page. Elsewhere I see references to Keywords and also Terms in a Termset. Are these all the same thing? Also, I can my my organizations Managed Termset, but I can't figure out exactly how to follow your instructions ("open up the settings for the categories field"). Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, don't get hung up on terms.  Think about it like this: wiki categories are a field of type managed metadata.  In order to use that field on your wiki, you need to assign it a termset from your managed metadata term store.  That's something you do in the column settings for the categories column.  I'll edit my answer in just a sec to include some screenshots (assuming I can pull that off without bringing down the iron hammer of infosec).

Comment: I never would have figured that out on my own!!

Comment: Glad I could help.  Mind marking it as the answer? ;)

Comment: Sorry I didn't do that. Since the system won't let me upvote due to lack of reputation, I didn't think I could do anything. BTW, it doesn't really make sense to me that I can't vote on the answer - whether or not I have the knowledge to contribute good answers, I think I can form an intelligent opinion on the helpfulness of existing answers.

Comment: There's a lot to the stackexchange philosophy that seems odd to me.  But I guess it has to be working, since you don't see a whole lot of bad behavior here.